# How to build stand-alone SOAP web services using Delphi?

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, indy

How can I build a stand-alone SOAP-based Web Services using Delphi? Must work with Delphi 2009, but it'd be nice if it worked with older ones too.

The built-in WebBroker Web Services creates CGI or ISAPI. It would be nice to create a stand-alone executable that I can control from bottom to top, especially during development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Dave Nottage](http://gp.embarcadero.com/authors/edit/1791.aspx) wrote [Building a stand-alone Web service with Indy](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27513) ([source code](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/16364)).

> This article explains how to fit Indy
>   into Delphi 6's Web services (SOAP)
>   support.

According to the comment on the page, it works with Delphi 2009 with some modification.

**Edit**: People in [Indy 10 and IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge with CBuilder 2009](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=63725) posted modified version. For example, [IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas](https://forums.embarcadero.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2-9780-66171-751/IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas) is by Jochanan van der Niet.

Answer (score 10):

[RemObjects SDK for Delphi (RO/Delphi)](http://www.remobjectssdk.com/delphi.aspx).

> Different messaging formats are
>   provided, including our own highly
>   efficient binary BinMessage format, as
>   well as support for SOAP, XML-RPC and
>   - new - JSON encoding, in case you want to make your servers accessible
>   to clients not using RO, or write
>   clients to access Web Services
>   provided by others.

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible to build a web service with VCL for the Web (formerly: Intraweb). It has an option of creating a standalone executable that contains both: web server and web application

Answer (score 3):

In D7 I used IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge (Indy 9). But i don't know if it is still available in D2009.

Answer (score 3):

There are a series of [SOAP articles](http://www.drbob42.com/soap/index.htm) on Dr. Bob's website and specifically there is RAD Studio 2007 XML, SOAP and Web Services Development manual, but it's 99 Euro.

Answer (score 2):

Something I used in the past was [idRunner](http://users.telenet.be/ws36637/) which is an extension to the indy library and it allows you to develop ISAPI dll's which your application then runs.  The advantage of this approach, is you can deploy a standalone application to run your soap service, that can easily be deployed via IIS at a later date.

For debugging, I strongly suggest the idDebugger on the same page.  It makes debugging ISAPI applications very easy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step-by-step solution "Delphi 7 Indy Standalone Web Services/SOAP Server" which looks like it can be useful for Delphi 2009 too:

http://www.digicoast.com/delphi_soap_standalone.html

Update:

this solutions uses IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge, it can be used in Delphi 2009 with minor changes.