# Delphi 2009: "XML document must have a top level element" error when using TIdHttpWebBrokerBridge

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

We have a app which uses HttpWebBrokerBridge, it works fine in Delphi2006 but when I recompile using Delphi2009 I get EDOMParserError exception with message "XML document must have a top level element".

I don't have any clues as to what's causing this error.

Any clues as to what I should do?

Sandeep

Comment: While tracing through HttpWebBrokerBridge I get exception in method DoCommanGet on line lWebModule.DispatchAction(LRequest, LResponse)

Answer (score 1):

See [How to build stand-alone SOAP web services using Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846207/how-to-build-stand-alone-soap-web-services-using-delphi/846210)

In particular,

> People in [Indy 10 and
>   IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge with CBuilder
>   2009](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=63725) posted modified version. For
>   example,
>   [IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas](https://forums.embarcadero.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2-9780-66171-751/IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas) is by
>   Jochanan van der Niet.

According to [Robert Petek](http://threads.embarcadero.com/threads/threads.exe/view?commentid=41840),

> I used Delphi 2009 with Indy 10 and
>   modified IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas a
>   bit. It looks the problem is in the
>   TIdHTTPAppRequest.GetStringVariable
>   function where Content property is
>   filled with
>   FRequestInfo.UnparsedParams. This is
>   empty when it gets a POST command.
>   I've debugged the code and saw the
>   contents is in the
>   FRequestInfo.PostStream.
>
> Try to set the result for the Content
>   property to the PostStream contents
>   when FRequestInfo.CommandType is
>   hcPOST. You will also need to fix the
>   result value for the ContentLength
>   property. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest 10.5.5 snapshot of Indy 10 from SVN's Tiburon branch.  Changes to TIdCustomHTTPServer and TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge were merged into that codebase awhile ago.