# Delphi 2006 Standalone Webserver compilation error

Tags: delphi, indy, embeddedwebserver

I'm trying to create a SOAP Server application that is a stand alone application (no need for IIS to be configured). The problem is that I get this error when trying to compile:

I get the error

> SockApp was compiled with a different version of IdTCPServer

Now this is because Delphi 2006 ships with INDY 10 but SockApp appear to have been compiled with INDY 9.

The read me states:

1. Include $(BDS)\Lib\Indy9 in the Library path and remove $(BDS)\Lib\Indy10. However, this forces the application to use Indy9.
2. Compile IndySockTransport and sockapp and put it in $(BDS)\Lib\Indy10.

Option 1 works, but I need to use some of the INDY 10 features so this is not a great option for me.

Does anyone know how to implement option 2? i.e. how do I compile IndySockTransaport and sockapp?

Comment: It is safer to put the source code for units which need to be recompiled either in the project folder or a dedicated folder, added to the project search path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also look here: http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-isapi-server/

It is simple to use, flexible (out of the box it works with Indy 9 and 10, but can work with any HTTP components) and tested. It is an ISAPI server side support, but you just build your SOAP module as ISAPI and it works as standalone server. You practically need only few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial covers the steps to build a standalone Soap Server using Indy 9 but it can be modified to work with Indy 10 too:

http://www.digicoast.com/delphi_soap_standalone.html

See also the accepted answer in [How to build stand-alone SOAP web services using Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846207/how-to-build-stand-alone-soap-web-services-using-delphi) with links to Indy 10 versions

Comment: Yes I've seen those two, the first can indeed be modified to work with INDY 10 but it requires SockApp to be recompiled which returns me to my original question. I've not managed to get the second example to work either, I can post error messages if interested.