# Indy 11 - What feature do you want to see?

Tags: delphi

If you could suggest only one new (or enhanced) feature for the Internet Direct (Indy) version 11, which one would it be?

Update: I found the first information about an upcoming Indy 11 version in question [Step by step upgrade of Indy 10 in Delphi 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204601/step-by-step-upgrade-of-indy-10-in-delphi-2009) (where Remy mentions plans for a new installer in a comment)

---

Some ideas from my side:

- a [RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918) ([WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV)) server implementation. Example use case: combined with the Explorer-based integration of WebDAV in Windows, such a server could play the role of a user-friendly document exchange gateway between a workstation and a legacy application
- a [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) implementation. It could bring push based services to Delphi applications to integrate with existing enterprise software systems (instead of frequent polling)
- support for [DNS SRV record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) entries
- a server and client side [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) implementation
- example for a standalone [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) server based on IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge (see [How to build stand-alone SOAP web services using Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846207/how-to-build-stand-alone-soap-web-services-using-delphi))

Comment: Are you going to participate in Indy 11 development or you are just curious?

Comment: installer != **library** feature, dont be such a lazy boy!

Comment: A good installer **is** a library feature, IMHO. That's where everything starts from...

Comment: ldsandon, why? for reinstalling library every other day?

Comment: No, to simplfy upgrades and ensure the installation is correct. Of course you can do without an installer, but that's one of the features that separates professionally developed libraries from the amateurish ones.

Comment: I have added WebDAV and XMPP to the list.

Answer (score 5):

Social client component interfaces  (Facebook / twitter)

Comment: Then remove them. They are not Internet standards, just application APIs. Otherwise you should add, for example, full Exchange (or Notes) support using their own APIs. THat would be much more useful than Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: Indy is not limited to implementing only Internet Standards.  It is first and foremost a Network Communications library.  Popular protocols are allowed.  I have added Exchange/Notes API support to the list, though I cannot promise it.